# GSM module connected with arduino uno giving garbage values in response

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, softwareserial

I connected a GSM module with the Arduino UNO. The connections are as follows:

> Gnd of gsm -----> Gnd of arduino
>
> TX of gsm  -----> pin 9 of arduino
>
> Rx of gsm  -----> pin 10 of arduino

GSM is powered from a 9V-1Amp wall adapter.

The GSM is performing according to all the `AT` commands (like making a voice call, hanging a call, answering a call) which are given, but it is displaying garbage values on serial monitor in response.

Here is the code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial myserial(9, 10);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    myserial.begin(9600);
    myserial.println("ATDXXXXXXXXXX;");
    delay(30000);
    myserial.println("ATH");
}

void loop() {
    if (myserial.available()>0){
        Serial.println(myserial.read());
    }
}
```

What could be reasons for the GSM to output garbage values and how can I resolve it?

Comment: 115200 baud is at the top end of what software serial can handle. It's probably failing miserably. Better to use hardware serial on a board with multiple UARTs.

Comment: @Majenko from the code, the OP is using `SoftwareSerial` at only 9600 then that should be fine.

Comment: @jfpoilpret It was hard to tell since the code was such a mess. Yes, I could have formatted it myself, but that's the job of the OP to do. If they can't even be bothered to do that, then... meh...

Comment: Could you post the garbage (and its value in hexadecimal if unprintable) you get?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Serial.println(myserial.read());
```

`myserial.read()` returns an integer. That integer is either the ASCII code of the next character in the buffer, or -1 if there is no character to read.

You then print that integer, each one on its own line.

So the response "OK\r\n" from, say, "AT\r\n" would look like:

```
79
75
13
10
```

Instead you need to `write` the data, not `print` it:

```
Serial.write(myserial.read());
```

Also, the way you have written your code, you will get no response for 30 seconds - that is, until everything has already happened. Only after it has all finished will you get some feedback - and that may not be complete since you may overrun the buffer depending on what the modem sends.

Comment: I tried using Serial.write() in place of Serial.println() but still I am getting the garbage values. The module is not responding even while sending an AT command through Serial Monitor.